# Insert extra row when Mr & Mrs found then copy data into blank row

Tags: excel, vba

So i have data which looks like this:

| Name | Title | Salutation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | Mr J & Mrs E | John & Elaine |
| Smith | Mr K & Mrs M | Ken & Margaret |
| Jones | Mr R | Bob |

I need to identify the rows which contain Mr & Mrs and give them each their own row. So I want it to look like this:

| Name | Title | Salutation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | Mr J | John |
| Doe | Mrs E | Elaine |
| Smith | Mr K | Ken |
| Smith | Mrs M | Margaret |
| Jones | Mr R | Bob |

Please could someone help with some code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below is coded for your three columns to be in Columns A, B, and C.  This loop works up from the bottom of your data to make it easier to deal with the inserted row.

```
Sub split_rows()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim title_position As Integer
    Dim saluation_position As Integer
    Dim title As String
    Dim salutation As String
    Dim last_row As Long
    
    Const name_column = 1
    Const title_column = 2
    Const salutation_column = 3
    
    
    Set s = ActiveSheet 'use the line to process the active sheet
    'set s = worksheets("Sheet1") ' use this line to process a specific sheet
    
    ' this loop works from the bottom of the worksheet up.
    ' the code is simpler that working top-down.
    last_row = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, title_column).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = last_row To 2 Step -1
        Debug.Print s.Cells(r, 1).Value
        title_position = InStr(1, s.Cells(r, title_column).Value, "&")
        saluation_position = InStr(1, s.Cells(r, salutation_column).Value, "&")
          
        If title_position > 0 And saluation_position > 0 Then
            ' found ampersands in title and salution, let's to split the data
            
            'put joint title and salutation values in variables to make the code easier to read
            title = s.Cells(r, title_column).Value
            salutation = s.Cells(r, salutation_column).Value
            
            s.Rows(r).Insert  ' add a row
            
            ' put the the name (unchanged) in the new row
            s.Cells(r, name_column).Value = s.Cells(r + 1, name_column).Value
            
            ' put half the title in each row
            s.Cells(r, title_column).Value = Trim(Split(title, "&")(0))
            s.Cells(r + 1, title_column).Value = Trim(Split(title, "&")(1))
            
            ' put half the salutation in each row
            s.Cells(r, salutation_column).Value = Trim(Split(salutation, "&")(0))
            s.Cells(r + 1, salutation_column).Value = Trim(Split(salutation, "&")(1))
      End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gove that's awesome! Just one little thing i have some Names in column  "Name" where the couple's surnames don't match i.e. Mr Smith & Miss Doe. These haven't been picked up with your code is there a little tweak needed please?

Comment: And also one more thing please - I would like to duplicate the data in the other columns in my table upwards into the new blank row - is this possible please?

Comment: @SophieMcLoughlin, I'm glad this works for you so far.  The idea was to get you some code to get you started.  Stack Overflow is a place where programmers help other programmers--even ones who are just beginning.  It's up to you to work with this start to meet your specific needs.  If this code as helped you get started, it would be appropriate for you to mark it as the selected answer.

Comment: Understood - thanks for your help Gove

Comment: @SophieMcLoughlin, By day, I'm a professor who teaches VBA to beginners.  I've posted videos of my lectures freely online.  It may be a good resource as you begin in this space. https://vba-course.blogspot.com/